# Reading From CursorWindow Error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a listView containing titles of notes for a note making application. I am trying to implement an itemclicklistener to open the respective notes.
   Here is the SQLite  table creation code:

```
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notes";
        public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
        public static final String DATA = "data";
        public static final String TITLE = "title";
String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + DATA + " text not null,"
            + TITLE + " text not null"
            + " ) ; ";
```

Here is the code to get the data:

```
 mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String data = (cursor.getString(2));
```

Problem is I get the title when i pass 1 to the cursor.getString(1) method where  instead I should be fetching data while passing 2 to the same throws a cursor initialization error.

Comment: So, how do you initialize your cursor?

Comment: Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCurrentRow` inside `onItemClick`, what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: Only the id and title. Data is nowhere to be seen,

Comment: You need to add data column to projection

Comment: Didnt get you..

Comment: Well got it to work thanks!

Comment: so you cannot call `getString(2)` if you have only two columns in your `Canvas`

Comment: Yes I forgot to include the data column while initializing the cursor for  creating the list view.

Comment: Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT *  from " + DBhandler.TABLE_NAME, null);
        String[] titles = new String[]{DBhandler.TITLE};
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notetitle, cursor, titles, new int[]{R.id.noteTitleText}, 0);
        mListView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

Comment: so it should work and dont use things like: `cursor.getString(2)` - use `getColumnIndex` instead

Comment: Ok thanks for the help